# Kotlin equivalent of python self.__dict__.get(item)

Tags: object, variables, kotlin, global

I am writing a storage class to store variables with unique IDs. In python, I used this. What would I use in Kotlin?

I already tried using what seemed like equivalents while looking through docs but none worked.

Comment: Are you looking for a data structure that store unique key-value pairs? If yes then use a HashMap. If you just want to store unique keys, then use a HashSet

Comment: Thank you, HashMaps are just what I am looking for. Answer the question and I can mark as correct.

Comment: Some helpful documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html#kotlin-collections-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is what you're looking for. Example:

```
val hashMap = HashMap<Int, String>()
hashMap.put(12, "str")
hashMap.put(-1, "something else")
```

Comment: Hello, there, I am trying .put but it isn't working:

        var storeMap = HashMap<String, String>()

        storeMap.put("text1", "This is the central hub")

Comment: @Spaceguy99 not enough info. YOu could create a new question for that